# Finding out the creation time of existing rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table where a fare amount of data already exists. Unfortunately, it doesn't have a column for timestamp and now I need the insertion dates of every row. If I add the current timestamp column now, will it generate the timestamps for existing rows? If not, what is the way to get those?

I have searched for the answer, but couldn't find anything satisfactory.

Comment: *If I add the current timestamp column now, will it generate the timestamps for existing rows?* The value for this column in all existing rows will be assigned to default value specified in this column options.

Comment: You cannot magically get historic insert dates. If you have daily backups you could have a go but it would be tedious time consuming and possibly not that accurate

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a column defined as timestamp in your table, the server doesn't store time information in the data file.

In this case, the only possibility to get the time values for data insertion or modification is to process the binary log files (which requires that the server variable `log_bin` was set to on when starting the server).

If you for example executed the following statement

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, "foo")
```

you can obtain the time of insertion (=1673625297) e.g. with mysqlbinlog utility by checking the SET TIMESTAMP command

```
#230113 16:54:57 server id 1  end_log_pos 25499425 CRC32 0xa56cd9e9     Query   thread_id=35677 exec_time=0     error_code=0    xid=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1673625297/*!*/;
insert into t1 values (1, "foo")

select from_unixtime(1673625297);
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1673625297) |
+---------------------------+
| 2023-01-13 16:54:57       |
+---------------------------+
```